# How to subsribe to firebase specific topic in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

package.json

```
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "8.4.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.8.6",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.2"
```

Currently, I'm able to receive push notification from web api that I have setup to send notification through fcm api.

Now, I want to implement the subscribeToTopic as the device will have different group of user. For example by combining companycode=F88 and departmentid=1:- `F881`. But I got error :-

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
> Error: [messaging/unknown] Invalid topic name:  does not match the allowed format [a-zA-Z0-9-_.~%]{1,900}.

I also try `F88.1`, `/topics/F88/1`. But I still get the error. I check the input string and the allowed format using regex tester and it is valid.

My implementation as below:-
root/src/navigator/navigationContainer.js

```
// This is minimal static code. 
// Real data will retrieve from web api login validation
const constTopic = 'F881';
export const StackNavigator = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
    });
    // Error on here
    firebase.messaging().subscribeToTopic(constTopic);
    return () => unsubscribe;
  }, []);
}
```

I want to subscribe certain topic after login has been validated(comes after click login or token found on AsyncStorage on splash screen). If not login, then it should show general notification only.